# Draw charts using c# with a lot of data

Tags: c#, charts

When i drew line charts using c# with a lot of data(maybe 10 million~100 million), it's not loaded. c# window form was broken.
i can't reduce these data because all of data are important.

Comment: See [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829655/how-can-i-plot-more-than-50-000-values-in-a-scatter-chart-saving-computer-resou/44907069#44907069).

Comment: this project was done. actually, it's not my project. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Surely it is impossible to show all 10 million data points on a screen. My current screen resolution at 1920x1080 only has about 2M pixels. So even if you show all the points from your data, there will not be enough screen space to show it all.
So you'll need to either reduce your data size by smoothing out the graph data or show only parts of your data at a time.

Comment: your answer is realistic. thanks for answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use for example [Oxyplot](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot) - you just bind data, and the library does all the work - zooming, paning, smoothing graphs.

Comment: thanks for answer to me. but somehow it didn't work as i expected.

Comment: what do you mean by that? I used this to make animated graohs with 60FPS while zooming and panning.

Comment: maybe, something was wrong when i tried. and this project was done. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a package like HoloView for Python - it supports big pictures with zoom in capabillity.

Comment: thanks for answer to me. but i'm not use Python this project.